# Efficient alternative to cvSet2D?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm profiling the code that I have developed, and I see a bottleneck in my code when I use cvSet2D.
Is there some alternative to cvSet2D more efficient?

How can I write that pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use the C++ functions and not the old C style functions.

The most efficient way to write to pixels is the following.

```
   cv::Mat frame;

   // load your img to your Mat

   uchar* p = frame.ptr(row); // returns a row pointer
   p[column] = x; // accesses value in the given column
```

One thing to note is that you might have more columns than you have pixel columns, e.g. on a 3 channel image you have 3 times the number of actual pixel columns you can access.

For more information on different ways to iterate over pixels, check [this](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv) tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much. Nice tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a pointer to the data field of the structure.

(C API) The IplImage structure has a char* field called data. Access `(your_type*)image->data` for the first element, and then use it like a regular C 1D array, but be careful to use the field stepWidth to jump from a line to the next (because lines of data may be aligned on multiples of 16 bits for memory access optimization).

(C++ API) Use `T* cv::Mat::ptr<T>(int i)` to get a pointer to the first element of the line you want to access. Then use as a regular C++ 1D array.

This should be the faster access pattern (see the book OpenCV2 Cookbook for a comparison of the different access patterns).